# как изменить Terarian в unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

у меня есть система гор сделанная через Terrarian. и я хочу сделать возможность копать его
(в смысле делать  шахты)
я нашёл возможность изменять его высоту. но дырки в нём делать не получается

есть вариант конвертировать Terrarin в модель, и деформировать её. но я не умею

*P.S. делать надо через Terrarian т.к. у меня процедурная генерация, а по другому я её делать тоже не умею*

Comment: Простых решений нет
Изучайте работу мешей

Comment: Единственный вариант начать уметь, с помощью террейн такое не делается. Самое простое, это научиться генерировать меш. Сгенерировать террейн самому довольно просто, это всего лишь `x, z` сетка с `y` высотами. А вот на создание топографически сложных вогнутых и выпуклых форм, это недели или даже месяцы изучения геометрии.